# Can't install Java JDK

Tags: java, cmd

Ok, this is embarrassing, but I can't install Java. I have no experience in Java so any help appreciated.

So as ussual I install Java JDK (The JRE I think is already there before) I have jre7 and jdk1.8.0.0_05

I have install it, but Java still not in my computer

Here's some desperate cmd check

```
>C:\>WHERE java
>INFO: Could not find files for the giving pattern
>C:\>java
>'java is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Where my java folder is C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0.0_5

On my desperation I created the variable JAVA_HOME on the given directory. Afterward, I tried this.

```
>C:\>echo %JAVA_HOME%

%JAVA_HOME%
```

I was expecting the cmd to echo the directory.

The variable PATHEXT has the following in it:

```
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

Clariffication:

I tried to reinstall the Java Jdk Installer with Windows Installer, but no luck.

If this matters, I'm running from Windows 7.

I tried to learn from  [Here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/setup-your-java-development-environment-in-windows-7.html)

After closer inspection, I can run java and javac after going all the way into the directory (so inputing java outside the bin will do nothing good)

Comment: `where` doesn't look for all files on your system.  It only looks for files that you would be able to execute without a full path name, which means files in your current directory and on the %PATH%.  Type `where/?` if you want more information about `where`.

Comment: By the way, I don't normally have `JAVA_HOME` set when I bring up a Command Prompt window, and the compiler still runs just fine.  I think this environment variable is needed for other installations that depend on Java, though.  But not for the Java compiler itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0.0_5\bin` to your PATH variable

Here is how mine is

[image]

Comment: I'm doing it, but no luck. But when I add the "/bin" to JAVA_HOME and call echo %JAVA_HOME%, it did echo the right directory. inputting java to cmd still give the same error.

Comment: Put it in PATH variable, JAVA_HOME not needed to access from `cmd`. Check my screen shot. The only difference is that I am using a 64 bit Java so it is in `Program Files` instead of `Program Files (x86)` and always restart `cmd` (command prompt) after changing the PATH variable. It needs to be closed and re-launched to get the new values

Comment: I did. I put in after the semicolon in the PATH. Do I need to go as far as uninstalling JRE, since the JRE and JDK in different version.

Comment: java is still not recognized. I called echo %path% to double check. It's still there the directory.

Comment: Check the jdk path.. I see a difference mine is - `jdk1.8.0_05` and yours is `jdk1.8.0.0_5`. Are you sure you typed the right one?

Comment: It seems to be a typo that I did. Still no luck after modifying it.

Comment: Now I am really confused, I don't see a reason that java will not be available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55536/discussion-between-activehigh-and-realdeo).

Comment: Thank you. I turns out, I need to put the java IN FRONT of others directory, not BEHIND others directory like your picture did. Thank you for the picture :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have not added JAVA_HOME environment variable, and/or to PATH environment variable neither.

Give a read to this article

http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/jdk_howto.html

Answer (score 0):

Regarding you last comment, i think you should put the java directory right infront of all the other directory because, if you were to install another version of java it might not be used if you place it behind.

(For Advanced Users Only)
I suggested that you place the JDK bin directory in front of "c:\windows\system32" and "c:\windows". This is because some Windows systems may have an out-dated copy of JDK/JRE in these directories. Do a search for "java.exe", and you will be amazed by the findings.
You could read "Java Applications and Environment Variable" for more discussions about PATH environment variable.
I also recommend that you define an environment variable called JAVA_HOME, which contains the JDK installed directory, and include the JDK bin directory in the PATH via JAVA_HOME, i.e., PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;.....